# How to fix code to return full list instead of one row from SqlDataReader in C# Web API

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am building a web API that connects to SQL and am trying to return all rows from the db in which the "StartDateTime" value is equal to today's date. For some reason, I am only getting one row instead of all rows that fit the definition. What do I need to change?

```
public class EventsController : ApiController
    {
        public List<tblEventDate> Get()
        {
        using (CalendarEntities entities = new CalendarEntities())
        {
            tblEventDate singleEvent = new tblEventDate();
            List<tblEventDate> eventList = new List<tblEventDate>();

            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnCalendar"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();

            string comm = "SELECT [dbo].[tblEventDates].[EventID], [dbo].[tblEventDates].[StartDateTime], WHERE (CONVERT(date, dbo.tblEventDates.StartDateTime) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, con);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        singleEvent.StartDateTime = (DateTime)(reader["StartDateTime"]);
                        singleEvent.EventID = (long)reader["EventID"];
                        eventList.Add(singleEvent);
                    }
                    reader.NextResult();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return eventList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting just one row, or the same row N times? You need to create a new `tblEventDate` instance (`singleEvent`) on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @madreflection thank you!!!

Comment: Does that mean it's working now?

Comment: @madreflection yes that was it

Comment: Great! Some review notes then, if I may: There's a bit of unused / unnecessary code here. The `entities` variable is unused. `reader.NextResult()` is unneecssary because you only have one query. `while (reader.HasRows)` is unnecessary because you're iterating through the rows with `reader.Read()`. You should be putting `using` blocks on the `con` and `cmd` variables (takes care of `con.Close()` for you, too).

Comment: I don't think you need reader.NextResult - I hadn't actually seen that method before but it appear to be when you are running multiple queries, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: @madreflection would you happen to also know how I can make the list I'm returning only include some of the columns but include columns from 2 different dbs (tblEventDate and tblEvents)?

Comment: @MayaBerk - Start by writing the query you want and running it in SSMS. Do the join on the tables, apply your predicate (where), project (select) the columns you want. Start from there. Then reduce the clutter (per my review notes) and use the reader to access the columns you need. Create another class for the result, because none or your entities will quite match, and return that instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you have an EF context... why did you break from it and use ADO.NET directly? Were you aware that EF can remove the time from a datetime using [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)? If you get that working, you could use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.HasRows)
  {
    singleEvent.StartDateTime = (DateTime)(reader["StartDateTime"]);
    singleEvent.EventID = (long)reader["EventID"];
    eventList.Add(singleEvent);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's cleaner but  don't think it will solve the problem (see what @madreflection has commented on the question)

Comment: `reader.HasRows` is superfluous within the loop. If `reader.Read()` returns `true`, there are values to access.